# Mathematical rigorous approach to linear regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, references, linear

I'd like a book or any PDF that teaches about linear regression in a complete way. That is, I want something that, for instance, doesn't use any random variable without stating its domain or the $\sigma$-algebra associated with it. Or at least tell which assumptions are being made (say which distributions are known and which are not, for example). In other words, I want a mathematical rigorous approach to linear regression (in the context of statistics).

If you know any book with these qualities, please tell me its name.

---

Unfortunately, all the material I've found disregards possible divisions by zero or considers that a matrix is invertible even if it has random variables in its coordinates whose images are not known.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: "Plane Answers to Complex Questions" by Christensen, and "Linear Models and Generalizations" by Rao are fairly rigorous, although I don't think they mention $\sigma$-algebras (nor do I see how that would be important for linear regression).

Comment: @angryavian Thank you very much! God bless you!